# What is a RTOS, is it embedded or do I need to install? (MSP430)

Tags: c, microprocessor, msp430, rtos

First of all, I have the basic knowledge in low-level programming of microprocessors but I don't have the in-depth details which I need. I have never worked with RTOS before in my previous class. Now my thesis advisor wants me to test if a RTOS is really real-time he probably already knows the answer.

I tried to research about RTOS and OS but I couldn't find a direct answer for my particular question.

I wonder, do I need to install the RTOS to the MSP430 before I write codes - or is it embedded. If it's not installed already, can I install it through UART and USB-emulator?

Why do I need RTOS?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Very broad topic. Research FreeRTOS - definitely easiest to start with and is supported on MSP430. Usually an RTOS is compiled alongside your main project ("include a magic library") and flashed to the MCU just like a bare-metal project. From a beginners perspective, an RTOS "makes several C functions appear to execute all in parallel".

Comment: This question is far too broad to fit within the mission of this site.  You need to be reading reference materials to gain an understanding of the subject (normally this would get some at least theoretical treatment in undergraduate coursework), and likely have a more in depth conversation with your advisor.

Comment: Sorry for the broad topic, should I delete it? I really couldn't find an answer in the reference manuals that I've been investigating so far. But I'll give a try to FreeRTOS. And thanks for the fast replies. @ChrisStratton

Comment: If sampling rate meets control latency needs then RTOS interrupt driven events are “real-time”. Like any OS , it must be uploaded into RAM unless ROM is adequate.

Comment: Although machine code programming is more efficient , it takes longer to develop complex functions.

Comment: @TonyEErocketscientist The MSP430 is a small 16-bit microcontroller. Programs generally run out of flash or FRAM memory. A typical unit might have 16K of flash and 0.512K of RAM so not much to work with (though it is supported by the  von-Neumann architecture).

Comment: If your advisor wants you to test an RTOS as "really real-time" then (1) the request seems strange if you are correct that your class never dealt with RTOS before; and, (2) your advisor would have to say a lot more about what the situation is before you could address the question -- the idea of "real-time" varies. In many of my applications, for example, I might require no more variance than \$1\:\mu\text{s}\$ (or less, even.) Others, getting the month of year right might be "real-time."

Comment: @SpehroPefhany http://processors.wiki.ti.com/index.php/MSP430_Real_Time_Operating_Systems_Overview

Comment: Thanks for all answers. I really had no idea. 

@jonk, I've made contact with my advisor long before the next term starts just in case that I could be able to fulfill all the requirements for my project. But he now probably wants more than then it could be managed in an education year because it's too early thus he is giving some directives for me to improve myself. 

I did this because I failed my other end-project due to lacking of knowledge and it is the only thing left for me to graduate.

Comment: @Mynameisname Okay. That's a good answer, I suppose. A very simple O/S may do very little: manage the allocation of memory and perhaps perform some services regarding separate stacks for threads and providing co-operative thread switching. Other O/S do much more. An RTOS will have a focus on providing services that make some time-guarantees and because of that almost always provides a new, important service called "pre-emptive scheduling." Preemption is often tricky, because it may interrupt library code that uses static data which may be over-written by another thread.

Comment: @Mynameisname But the design of an application to use an RTOS is far and away the more important side. An RTOS might provide certain guarantees, but it usually requires some very crafted, careful thinking about designing your application to fit those services well. And that will be the more important aspect. I always write the RTOS from scratch to meet the embedded application's needs closely. Keeps the RTOS small and the application small, too. And provides a perfect fit, every single time. I've never used a commercial RTOS. (But then, I worked on Unix v6 kernel in '78 so I'm comfortable.)

Comment: All what you've written above are very enlightening for me. Now I can approximately research more precisely which was my main goal when asking the question. Really thanks for your time. @jonk

Comment: @Mynameisname Best wishes on getting completing your graduation requirements. Just keep in mind that an RTOS is about TIME. I'd mentioned (a jitter of) \$1\:\mu\text{s}\$ for example. Note the new term -- jitter. A tight RTOS will have very low jitter (some of mine have a jitter measured at \$20\:\text{ns}\$.) A sloppy RTOS might have jitter a million times worse, or more. Broadly, an RTOS should be able to switch to a high priority "ready" task very quickly AND ALSO very consistently. Consistency is more important because its possible to design around "slow" as long as it is "predictable."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably using Code Composer Studio or some other IDE. You will include the RTOS library  (eg. TI-RTOS) with your code and it will be compiled and flashed** into the MCU memory. See, for example, [this](http://www.ti.com/lit/ug/spruhu4e/spruhu4e.pdf) document.

(it's a bit buzzword-rich, but describes the functionality) This is a pre-emptive multitasking RTOS.

> TI-RTOS is a scalable, one-stop embedded tools ecosystem for TI devices. It
>   scales from a real-time multitasking kernel (SYS/BIOS) to a complete RTOS
>   solution including additional middleware components and device drivers. By
>   providing essential system software components that are pre-tested and preintegrated,
>   TI-RTOS enables you to focus on creating your application.
>   TI-RTOS is not installed automatically as part of the Code Composer Studio v6.x
>   installation. You can install TI-RTOS from the CCS App Center (choose View >
>   CCS App Center in CCS). Choose the version of TI-RTOS for your device family.
>   If you use devices in multiple families, you can install multiple TI-RTOS versions

** Or whatever the verb is for programming their ferroelectric memory variants.. FRAM'd ?

Comment: Maybe 'domained' or 'cored' :-).